# Change display position of "comment" popup in Facebook Like Button

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

Good evening!
I am currently developing a website which includes the Facebook Like Button. This button is located at the bottom of the page. When I click the button, the "comment" popup is displayed below the button, which extends my page. I would like to know whether (and, if so, how) it is possible to have the "comment" popup be displayed on top of the button or hide the popup permanently. 
The image below depicts my problem (the horizontal white bar is supposed to be at the bottom of the page, notice how the "comment" popup extends the page).

[image: Facebook like button popover.]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual website, I imagine you could just use css to select that popup and set it's display property to none. However you might need to use an !important statement to override any css property being set on that popup with javascript.

Example code:

```
.popup {
    display:none!important;
}
```

Comment: @salmoally, Facebook plugins uses `iframe`, you can't do any changes because of the cross-domain policy

Comment: @Adam Azad, you are right, looks like you can't even configure that popup. Not ideal but perhaps the layout could be adjusted so the like button isn't at the bottom of the page...

Comment: Thank you all for your time. I thought moving the like button from the bottom of the page was the last resort, but if it's the only option, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the popup box. Make sure your facebook like button layout type is button i.e. In your code snippet that facebook provides there should be `data-layout="button"`

and use this css

```
.fb-like{
   overflow: hidden !important;
}
```